# Vertical tabbar in objective-c for iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have to implement a vertical tabbar for the iPad in objective-c similar to this example: [Example](http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/087/Purple/e7/d6/55/mzl.tqvwiimj.1024x1024-65.jpg). I will have to use a UISplitViewController and somehow place the UIButtons inside the details view. I am grateful for any ideas.

Comment: in your example where is the vertical tab bar? everywhere is  customize TebleView.and if You think  in the right side of an image there is 4 tab bar button, then you are thinking wrong.there is no need of tab bar,you simply take 4 Custom UIButton and set the frame according to your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still wants to implement that thing using Vertical TabBar, You can check this [link](https://github.com/nst/SEVerticalTabBar)